# Redirect echo netcat output to docker log or stdout

Tags: linux, docker, logging, stdout

I wanted to know how I can redirect the output of an ECHO command to docker log or to its stdout?

I have the following command:

```
echo "CREATE (data) AT (/home/docker)" | nc data-container 8081 2>&1
```

But it doesn't work. Any other ideas?

Comment: Can't you send the output through > to nc, instead of piping?

Comment: Norp. Any ideas?